# How to display new or modified lines between two files using Python

Tags: python-2.7, diff

I have two files: file1.txt and file2.txt. I would like to only display the lines in result2.txt that are new / different from those in result1.txt.

I do this in bash using the following command:

> diff file1.txt file2.txt | grep -E "^>" | sed 's/^..//'

Is this achievable using Python (without calling an OS command)?

Answer (score 1):

See [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) a Python library for exactly this

Answer (score 0):

Go through the program and it is one of the lucid code, which takes advantage of a user defined function to look for changes between two files.
~~ do leave the comment if there is any queries.

```
def copy(name1 = input("Enter The Initial File Name : "), name2 = input("Enter The Change File Name : "), name3 = input("Enter The Nanme of The Output File : ")):
#initialisation from user if no parameter is provided    
    import os #to remove redundant output file, can be not used also    
    while True:

        try:
            f = open(name1,"r+") #'r+' because to read and write
            s = open(name2,"r+")
            o = open(name3,"w")

        except IOError:

            print("File not found !!!!")
            break

        while True:

            char1 = f.read(1)
            char2 = s.read(1)
            if (char1 == "" and char2 == ""): 
                break #if reached end of file
            if(char2 == ""):
                o.write(char1) #writing for difference in blank space
            elif(char1 == ""):
                o.write(char2) #writing for difference in blank space
            elif(char2 is not char1):
                o.write(char2) #compare and write

        f.close()
        s.close()
        o.close()
        print("The Changes Copied to",name3)
        break

copy()
```